# Does this series converge ? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln2\ln3\dots\ln(n+1)}{\ln(2+a)\ln(3+a)\dots \ln(n+1+a)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln2\ln3\dots\ln(n+1)}{\ln(2+a)\ln(3+a)\dots \ln(n+1+a)}$$ where $a>0$. I tried to see if it converges or not with Raabe Duhamel , but it gets really nasty and I'm not sure of the outcome.Any help is welcomed.

Comment: I hope I didn't mess up edit.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha nope thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a=1$ the series is

$$\sum\frac{\ln(2)\ln(3)\dotsm\ln(n+1)}{\ln(3)\ln(4)\dotsm\ln(n+2)}=\sum\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(n+2)}$$

This series is equivalent to $\sum \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. Since the latter diverges, the first one also diverges.

When we make $a$ smaller, the terms of the series increase. Therefore, if $a\in(0,1]$ the series is larger than for $a=1$ so it also diverges.

Similarly, for $a$ natural number, we similarly get

$$\ln(2)\ln(3)\dotsm\ln(a+1)\sum \frac{1}{\ln(n+2)\dotsm\ln(n+a)\ln(n+1+a)}$$

This series is equivalent to $\sum \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^a}$.

Since this series diverges, the original series also diverges. For non-integer values of $a$ we compare with the series for $a:=[a]+1$. Since the terms are decreasing in $a$. The series will also diverge.

Comment: This answer is false. First, $\sum \ln (n)^{-k}$ diverges no matter what $k$ is (these are *not* Rieman sums!), so the series diverges for integer $a$, and by monotonicity for any $a$. The first majoration in the argument with the geometric series is in the wrong direction.

Comment: @D.Thomine You haven't read the whole thing. First of all, the first majorization is in the right direction. As $a$ decreases, the denominators decrease. So the series gets larger. If the series diverges already for $a=1$ then it diverges for $a<1$ too. The only error is in stating that $\sum (\ln(n))^{-2}$ converges. But if you continue reading you will see there is an argument that finishes the proof for $a>1$.

Comment: Don't accuse me because of your errors, and don't assume that I haven't read what you have written. Thanks. Anyway, the inequality $\ln(3)/\ln(3+r) \ln(4)/\ln(4+r) ... \leq (\ln(3)/\ln(3+r))^{n-1}$ is false: the inequality is actually in the other direction.